# How can I remove curly quotes if available at 0 and last index of string in php?

Tags: php, drupal-8

How can I remove my $checkChar values if available at 0 and last index of string in php?

Condition is not working with Curly quotes.

I am trying this.

```
$checkArr = ['"', '“', '”'];
$str['quote'] = "“This is a sample text.”";

foreach ($checkArr as $key){
  if($str['quote'][0] === $key || $str['quote'][strlen($str['quote']) - 1] === $key {
    $str['quote'] = str_replace($key, '', $str['quote']);
  }
}
```

Comment: `ltrim` and `rtrim` would seem appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`trim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove quotes from the outside of the string:

```
$checkArr = ['"', '“', '”'];
$str['quote'] = "“This is a sample text.”";

echo trim($str['quote'], implode('', $checkArr));
```

Output:

```
This is a sample text.
```

**Note**

If you have multiple quotes on the outside the string, they will *all* be removed e.g.

```
$checkArr = ['"', '“', '”'];
$str['quote'] = "““This is a sample text.””";

echo trim($str['quote'], implode('', $checkArr));
```

Output:

```
This is a sample text.
```